# Page numbering in longtable

Tags: page-numbering, longtable

I have a table that needs to span on multiple pages. For this I've used `longtable`.

For each page that the table spans i need to specify something like page current_page/total_number of pages (not for the whole document, just the pages that the table is using).

Is there any way of doing this using `longtable` and/or other environments

Comment: _where_do you want the number to appear, table body, page head or table head. (table head would require large rewites of longtable as it saves the head in a box and doesn't re-set it each page. Or supertab is an option that does reset the heading each page

Comment: With no more information given, this is 'too localized', but will be reopened if there is more info.

Comment: This problem is precisely what I have now.