# Use page number in longtable

Tags: longtable, page-numbering

I am using `longtable` and want to access the page number from within the longtable, as in this bare-bone example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l}

longtable header: this is page \thepage
\endhead

A \\ 
A \\ 
A \\ 
... however many rows ...
... needed to exceed one page ...

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

However, the generated PDF always shows `this is page 1` in the longtable header, even if it is on page 2.

According to a comment to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65108/page-numbering-in-longtable), longtable "saves the head in a box and doesn't re-set it each page". The comment seems to suggest that the rolling page number simply cannot be accessed from within a longtable without a major rewrite. Do I understand that correctly? (I certainly hope that I do *not* understand it correctly, so there's still some hope that it can be done.)

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you :https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157193/134144. Alternatively, you could use the `supertabular` pakage as described in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373987/134144.

Comment: If you knew the name/register number of the box where the header is saved, you might be able to replace it globally using the afterpage package, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: you do understand it correctly, you can refer to a page with `\pageref` in the body of the table but not in the head. (there is an answer on this site somewhere that has some fragile code that tries to work round this)

Comment: or perhaps I didn't add any code, I  think this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46205/change-running-heads-in-longtable-or-other-long-table-package/46213#46213

Answer (score 1):

This sort of works.  I can't figure out where the left margin comes from though.  Also, for some reason the page counter wasn't working.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{everypage}

\newcounter{mypage}
\setcounter{mypage}{1}

\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{\stepcounter{mypage}%
  \ifdim\ht\LT@head>0pt
    \dimen0=\ht\LT@head
    \global\setbox\LT@head=\vbox to\dimen0{\strut
      longtable header: this is page \themypage}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l}
longtable header: this is page \thepage
\endhead
\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.7\textheight}\\
\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.7\textheight}\\
\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.7\textheight}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```